# Custom object detection in Java for Android

Tags: java, python, android, tensorflow, object-detection

I have been working on a custom object detection model where I have a set of images and those need to be identified in another image and in real-time using a phone camera. I am wondering whether it is possible to create a custom model without having to use YOLO or other pre-defined models? As well as if I train the custom model in Python using Tensorflow, Keras, is it possible to export that model to use in Java for an android application?

I have heard of using`CustomVision` from Azure, but I have to label each image manually, rather than just using the filename of the image, which becomes time consuming when having a large dataset.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can use tensorflow model server and a java client https://github.com/sumsuddin/TensorflowObjectDetectorJava

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Comment: I had taken a look at it, but it seems that is also using a pre-trained model, but I feel like I can adapt it in a way. I will give this technique a try and see what happens.